# Can't decide which data to use for summary statistics

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'm writing a report (for school) and I need to take data from my Excel to include in the report. One of the requirements is to include summary statistics (mean, mode, median, standard deviation) but I can't figure out which groups of data I'm meant to assemble for that. I was thinking the age groups but I think I've messed that up as the classes are not specific enough.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzEBSlO_8OEMkxRYzRVMjZ6VDQ/view

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more information here before this is answerable. People aren't going to want to click a link to answer your question for you. You're best bet, really, is to ask the instructor what they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer depends on your research question. If it relates to analyzing the survey data to provide an understanding of how consumers' behavior vary through age groups, then it's probably the way to go.

I will advise you to report summary statistics for the full sample, then by age category including the number of respondents per category. This will give a summary of the data at hands.